# Sequential search inquiry

Tags: c++

Hello guys I'm here to seek for help to finish my program. Well the code below runs but it doesn't perform all of the tasks it should do. The program should ask the user to input 5 numbers to be stored in an array. Second, it should ask the user what number inside the array he wants to find. After that, if the number is found in the array, it should display its location (index/indexes) and if not, it should display that the number is not within the array.

My problem is that even though the number to be searched is not within the array, it still displays an index. And another problem is that when I input common numbers in an array for example I want to search for 3: {3,3,54,0,8} it just displays the index of the "first" number three and doesn't display the index of the "second" number three. Please help me thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int list[5], a, loc = 0, searchItem, listLength;
    bool found = false;

    cout<<"Enter 5 numbers: "<<endl;
    for(a = 0; a < 5; a++)
               cin >> list[a];

    cout<<"\n\tEnter the number you want to find :";
    cin>>searchItem;

        while(loc < listLength && !found)
                  if(list[loc] == searchItem)
                     found = true;
                  else
                     loc++;
        if(found)
            cout << "\n\t\t " << searchItem << " is found at index " << loc << endl;
        else
            cout << "\n\n\tThe " << searchItem << " is not in the array" << endl;


getch();    
}
```

Comment: `listlength` never gets set to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets suppose, 4 exists two times in array. in your while loop, when 4 is found once, **found** variable is set to true. which is the breaking condition of loop. as you have written:

```
while(loc < length && !found)
```

This is why, it only finds the digit 4 one time, where it exists twice. try to fix this.
(hint: you may use for loop, for ease, or set found=false at the end of each iteration)

And if element is not within the array, it **doesn't** display it's index. try it carefully again.

**Edit:** 
here's the way you do it, as you asked for.
replace your **while** with **for** and simply you get this working:

```
int list[5], a, loc = 0, searchItem, listLength;
bool found = false;

cout<<"Enter 5 numbers: "<<endl;
for(a = 0; a < 5; a++)
           cin >> list[a];

cout<<"\n\tEnter the number you want to find :";
cin>>searchItem;



    for(loc = 0;loc < 5; loc++)
    {
        if(list[loc]==searchItem)
        {
             cout << "\n\t\t " << searchItem << " is found at index"<<loc<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "\n\n\tThe " << searchItem << " is not in the array"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: @Zeeshan-How can I do that? Could you please give a sample? I'm just a beginner but I really want to learn

Comment: sure thanks I'll study what code you'll give me and I'll appreciate it very much

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya did you understand the concept of conditioning while loop? did you understand why it could not find the integer, which exists twice in array? (by the way, your code will work fine, if array elements are unique)